# WP7 other application bar?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can I use another bar application that ApplicationBar of WP7?
I would have a recurrence of this type iPhone toolbar:
[iPhone toolBar](http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/8249/screenshot002ew.png)

Does it pass the certification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should pass certification, but I would advise against using it.  You are breaking the model that Microsoft spent do much effort to set up, and that users expect.  WP7 is not iOS, and it really shouldn't be made to look / feel like iOS, in my opinion.

Comment: My opinion is egualement in your direction, but not that of my boss ... : '(

Comment: Ah, the "Boss Factor".  Not a lot you can do about that. :(